# Flyway Community edition filtering out resource Java file - why?

Tags: java, classpath, flyway

I'm using the Community version of Flyway.  What Flyway is doing:

```
...
DEBUG: Found resource: myfolder/V1.2__description1.java
...
DEBUG: Filtering out resource: myfolder/V1.2__description1.java (filename: V1.2__description1.java)
...
```

My "locations" folder is correct:

```
flyway.locations=classpath:myfolder
```

I've even tried setting jarDirs setting (it did nothing to help):

```
flyway.jarDirs=myfolder
```

Why can't Flyway print out "why" a file/resource is being filtered out?

Do I also have to compile the Java file into a class file? The Flyway documentation didn't say to do that.

Comment: The Java code should not be a resource, it should be with the code (e.g. in `src/main/java`, not `src/main/resources`), because it must be compiled. The Flyway documentation probably doesn't mention it because that is assumed to be obvious.

Comment: And in fact, the documentation does mention it (see [Migrations - Java-based migrations - Discovery](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/migrations-184127470.html#Migrations-Discovery.1), compared to [Migrations - SQL-based migrations - Discovery](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/migrations-184127470.html#Migrations-Discovery))

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I did see the src/main/java tree in the documentation before submitting this.  However, I'm not making these Java migrations specifically for a _Java application_ (there is no "code") - let's say for example I am making these Java migrations for an IIS, PHP, Angular or (none; i.e., there is no) application.  Let's say I'm wanting to do a database migration by itself even.  I was wondering how the .java files would be compiled (or if I should compile them myself).  In the mean time, I'll compile my .java to .class and retry.

Comment: Flyway itself is besides a library, also a Java application. If you want it to execute a Java migration, that Java migration needs to be compiled and on the classpath when Flyway runs. Otherwise, you should use a SQL migration.